# kids between x and z years old or year old

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural, grammatical-number

I am confused which one should I use?

> 10% of kids between 9 and 12 **year old**

Or,

> 10% of kids between 9 and 12 **years old**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use your structure then "years old" is better.  The first sounds like "between a 9 year old child and a 12 year old child" (as the children are standing in a line)

This is the same as "He is five years old" compared with "He is a five-year-old child"

Though I might use "10% of kids between the ages of 9 and 12."